# PHP SQL - Upon PHP INSERT, add info from other table

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I have a currently working site where CSV files are uploaded and all 228 fields are inserted into a staging table in my database. However, the last 12 are pricing fields and are blank on the CSV.

The goal is, when the CSV is Inserted upon submit, I need to have a condition for certain meter sizes (3", 6") and tests (onsite,offsite) that match to a price table in the database.

For instance, If I have a price table that has "Onsite Only(product) - $250(price)", I would like the SQL statement to check the onsite only field in the CSV and if it's populated then it would grab that price from the price table and also insert it into the staging table.

Basically, when the CSV is submitted, the last 12 fields should not be blank but instead be filled with prices based on certain other fields in the CSV. I can map the conditions but I'm not sure how I would make this statement for my insert.

Here's my current loop and statement (columns and elements are stored in arrays):

```
$tablenames =    array("staging"/*,"clients","meters","tests","costs","workorders"*/);



for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++){
$q = "";
//$q2 = "";
//$q3 = "";
//$q4 = "";
//$q5 = "";
//$q6 = "";
$col_list = '`'.str_replace(',','`,`',$table_cols[$tableno]).'`';
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$col_list.") VALUES (";
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$cols = explode(",",$table_cols[$tableno]);
$data = array();
foreach($cols as $key => $fldname) {

    $data[] = "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $coldata[$fldname])."'";

}

/*INSERT INTO STAGING TABLE - INITAL CSV UPLOAD*/
$q .= implode(",",$data).");";
```

Comment: @HNorman, please show the schema of the pricing table, along with the relations needed to locate the price in that table.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I'm actually still rebuilding that table, but basically we will have priceID, part/service, laborCost, partCost, totalCost. Then I have an html table with rows for each part or service and columns for the three costs. The staging table already populates the rest of the HTML tables, I just need to check one table for work order type, and if it's checked it will fill the price for that work order type. If that makes sense.

Comment: Makes sense, but if you want an answer, you'll have to provide more details. It can probably be done with a SQL UPDATE after the initial import, but no way to tell without specifics. It's also possible to do during the import if all the info is in the CSV.

Comment: Ok, all costs are actually blank on the CSV importer, but they are static prices in the separate table, so the main thing is just to reference them when populating the html tables on a different page. Once it's done I can post better details here though, thank you!